# Clarifications on the Incompleteness Theorems

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory, incompleteness

I wanted to clarify my understanding of the big picture of the first Incompleteness Theorem and a question about the second.

1. The big picture of the first Incompleteness Theorem is that PA (or any other axiomatization of arithmetic) fails to define a unique model up to isomorphism. The axioms allow for the existence of models that are *different* in some important way (not elementarily equivalent). For some statement(s), one model thinks it's true and the other doesn't think it's true leading to the "true, but unprovable statements". Additionally, that a sentence is not provable from the axioms because two models disagree on the truth of the sentence is a consequence of the Completeness Theorem.

**Is this a correct understanding of the first Incompleteness Theorem?**

**Side Note**: If my understanding of the first Incompleteness Theorem is accurate, then the "true, but unprovable" characterization seems like a terrible description of it because it seems to leave out the important fact that truth is relative to a model. I'm thinking it is better so say something like, "true in $\mathbb{N}$, but unprovable from PA".

2. And the second Incompleteness Theorem says that the consistency of PA is precisely one of those statements where two models disagree on its truth. *I can't express how bizarre this is to me*. **How could a model of PA think PA is inconsistent?** Intuitively, this makes no sense to me.
3. Is there any understanding of what kinds of properties theories that behave well (define their models up to isomorphism) have? ...I guess one thing they have is that they can't be strong enough to do arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: (1), you're correct (and I agree with your side note). The one quibble I have is with the order of things: you seem to view the incompleteness theorem as a result about models which then gets turned into a result about proofs via Completeness, but it's actually the other way around.

Re: (2), [this old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287867/how-to-think-about-theories-that-prove-their-own-inconsistency) is relevant.

Re: (3), such a theory is called **(fully) categorical**. In first-order logic, as a consequence of the [compactness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem) (which can be proved as a corollary of the completeness theorem), there are no fully categorical theories at all (barring those theories of *finite* structures). We can however talk about categoricity *in a given cardinality*. For $\kappa$ an infinite cardinal, a *(complete, consistent, and with no finite models)* theory $T$ is **$\kappa$-categorical** iff $T$ has exactly one model, up to isomorphism, of cardinality $\kappa$. There are indeed interesting things we can say about this more restrictive kind of categoricity:

- If $T$ is countable, then there are only two kinds of categoricity: $T$ is categorical in *some* uncountable cardinal iff $T$ is categorical in *every* uncountable cardinal. So we just have $\aleph_1$-categoricity and $\aleph_0$-categoricity. This is [Morley's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_theory). Once we look at uncountable theories things get more complicated; see e.g. [this exposition of Harrington and Makkai](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ndjfl/1093870822).
- Within the context of countable theories, we can identify relevant model-theoretic properties. On the $\aleph_0$-categoricity side, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega-categorical_theory#Equivalent_conditions_for_omega-categoricity); for some information about uncountably categorical theories, see here.

Finally, I have to mention the hilarious Vaught's Never-Two Theorem: no complete countable theory has *exactly two* countable models up to isomorphism. Yes, we can get every natural number *except* two.

Comment: 1) Ahh yes. Thanks for that point. I guess the ordering is important epistemologically. 2) Thanks a lot for this! That was really insightful! So if I understood that correctly, this number that "witnesses" the proof of a contradiction is not one of the original encodings? Is there a way to restrict the existential quantifier of the existence of a proof of a contradiction to those which are meaningful encodings? 3) So you're saying if I take an ultrafinitist position, I'm all good? Just kidding. That's really interesting! Thanks a lot for the information!

Answer (score 0):

Noah's answer is good as usual, but I'll add a few things.

1. Regarding your side note, that "true" means "true in $\mathbb N$ is a common point of confusion. This often goes unexplained, because as Noah suggests, the core of Godel's theorem really isn't about model theory per se, and many expositors simply don't want to get into model theory. (But perhaps then they should resist the urge to mention truth at all.) And I'll second Noah's remarks that everything you say is correct, but the "models first" perspective is a bit cart-before-horse.
2. It might *seem* bizarre, but if you think hard about it you'll see that there's really no reason a model of PA should go one way or another about some statement that is undecidable in PA. Being a model of PA just means it needs to agree with PA on the things that PA can prove. There's nothing particularly special about the consistency of PA in this regard, it's just like any other PA-undecidable statement... the fact that it's "about" PA in some sense doesn't change anything. Models of PA can be wrong about all sorts of stuff, where of course "wrong" means they disagree with $\mathbb N$. And indeed, the completeness theorem indicates that there will be models of PA that are wrong about *any* PA-undecidable statement. $^*$
3. Remarkably, no first order theory with infinite models has a unique model up to isomorphism. This even includes complete theories that evade the incompleteness theorem by not including enough arithmetic (e.g. Presberger and Skolem arithmetic) as well as complete theories that evade the incompleteness theorem by not being recursively axiomatizable (like the theory of $\mathbb N$, i.e. "true arithmetic"). In the complete case, all models are elementarily equivalent, but they can never all be isomorphic. This follows from compactness / Lowenheim-Skolem, which imply that models with many different cardinalities exist. To get fully categorical theories, say ones that can axiomatize $\mathbb N$ up to isomorphism, we need stronger semantics, for example the standard semantics of second order or infinitary logic. (This doesn't solve any foundational problems, or evade incompleteness in any meaningful way, though.)

$^*$ For brevity, I've omitted a lot of hedging and handwringing that might be prudent from a foundations perspective. In particular, I'm implicitly assuming PA to be sound (with respect to $\mathbb N$), which is stronger than even assuming consistency.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to agree with you on 2), but that the statement is "about" PA does indeed make me want to say there's something going on there. If the statement truly does express the consistency of PA, that is. I'm really interested in the uses of 2nd and higher order logics for foundations. What do they give us that FOL doesn't? And why don't they solve any foundational issues in a meaningful way? (I guess I'm asking for a lot there) About your last point (*), I am not quite following. What do you mean by you are assuming PA to be sound with respect to $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @ElGalloNegro Will reply to the other stuff when I have more time, but by "sound with respect to $\mathbb N$", I mean that it doesn't prove any statements that are false in $\mathbb N.$ For 2) I might say more later, but for now it might help if I add that the model theoretic way of looking at it is that a nonstandard model will have nonstandard elements that it thinks are codes of proofs, and one of these proofs might be of inconsistency. All the real proofs are encoded by standard naturals. (This is how it gels with the fact that proofs are 'effective'.)

Comment: @ElGalloNegro Regarding second order logic, what I was getting at is that the fact that second order arithmetic is categorical (i.e. its only model is $\mathbb N$) doesn't mean that the incompleteness theorem does not apply to it. This is because SOL doesn't have a completeness theorem, so there isn't an equivalence between semantic and deductive consequence like there is for FOL. In any proof system for SOL, there are undecidable statements, by the same argument as for FOL, there just aren't any corresponding nonstandard models (that is, with respect to standard semantics for SOL).

Comment: ...doesn't soundness of PA with respect to $\mathbb{N}$ follow from the Soundness Theorem? For 2), this reminds me of the paper by Artemov a little while ago that—if I understood it correctly. His proposal was that consistency should be thought about as a scheme like induction over $\mathbb{N}$. It makes sense to do that if the issue in the current setting is non-standard natural numbers getting recognized as real encoded proofs when they are not. And thank you for the clarification on the SOL stuff!

Comment: @ElGalloNegro Soundness theorem says any theorem is true in all models, so it follows that if $\mathbb N$ is a model of PA then PA is sound with respect to it. It’s the “$\mathbb N$ is a model of PA” part that is controversial. For instance, if one has any doubt about the consistency of PA one must surely doubt that $\mathbb N$ is a model of PA, or doubt that that statement has any meaning. (Incidentally, there is space to doubt the soundness while believing the consistency... it is even remotely possible that PA proves its own inconsistency, but I don’t know anyone who believes this.)

Comment: @ElGalloNegro (I should clarify: it is remotely possible that PA proves its own inconsistency *but is consistent*. In this case it would be consistent but unsound (and not $\omega$-consistent). Also while I don’t know of anyone who believes this about PA - generally people either strongly believe in soundness or doubt consistency - I’ve heard people say they believe or take seriously the possibility that ZFC is consistent but not arithmetically sound.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am just seeing this last response, but is $\mathbb{N}$ being a model of PA really controversial? Which axiom is it that people think is not true for the natural numbers? It even seems silly to doubt induction. And arithmetically sound meaning it proves some untrue statements of arithmetic?

Comment: @ElGalloNegro Yes on arithmetically sound. $\mathbb N$ being a model of PA is settled fact in mainstream math, but it is controversial in the sense that there are heterodox views on foundations that are taken seriously (broadly speaking) that doubt such an idea. You may want to read up on finitism. The issue often isn't with induction per se, but with the idea of an arbitrarily complex first order property of natural numbers, which are the properties PA's induction scheme ranges over. A finitist may well be comfortable with PRA, which has an induction scheme but unlike PA, no quantifiers.

Comment: @ElGalloNegro I happened across some remarks sympathetic to this view: https://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2011-May/015509.html which is a reply to https://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2011-May/015490.html ... the overall context being that Voevodsky had given a talk where he said PA was probably inconsistent and quite cavalierly dismissed all the evidence to the contrary.